# Chat Bubble Alignment on ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getview

I have connected my android application to Firebase and I am sending messages with attributes 'name' and 'status'. status being either sent or received.
I am facing issue while aligning the chat bubble left/right depending upon the status.

Here is the code snippet

**message_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/message_bubble_received">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:text="Hello bubbles!"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="1dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:text="Hello bubbles!"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: message_row.xml design]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ECECEC">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="@null"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/form"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:autoText="true"
    android:background="@drawable/note_backgroud"
    android:hint="Write your question here"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/camera"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-52dp"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/chatSendButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/sent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Send"
    android:onClick="onSendButtonClick"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: activity_main.xml design]

Following is the code snipet for the MessageAdapter

**MessageAdapter.java**

```
public abstract class MessageAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {

private Query mRef;
private Class<T> mModelClass;
private int mLayout;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<T> mModels;
private List<String> mKeys;
private ChildEventListener mListener;
private Context context;
private LinearLayout message_row;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


public MessageAdapter(Query mRef, Class<T> mModelClass, int mLayout, Activity activity) {
    this.mRef = mRef;
    this.mModelClass = mModelClass;
    this.mLayout = mLayout;
    this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    mInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    mModels = new ArrayList<T>();
    mKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    mProgressDialog.show();
    // Look for all child events. We will then map them to our own internal ArrayList, which backs ListView
    mListener = this.mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            T model = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageAdapter.this.mModelClass);
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            // Insert into the correct location, based on previousChildName
            if (previousChildName == null) {
                mModels.add(0, model);
                mKeys.add(0, key);
            } else {
                int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
                int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
                if (nextIndex == mModels.size()) {
                    mModels.add(model);
                    mKeys.add(key);
                } else {
                    mModels.add(nextIndex, model);
                    mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // One of the mModels changed. Replace it in our list and name mapping
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            T newModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageAdapter.this.mModelClass);
            int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);

            mModels.set(index, newModel);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // A model was removed from the list. Remove it from our list and the name mapping
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);

            mKeys.remove(index);
            mModels.remove(index);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            // A model changed position in the list. Update our list accordingly
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            T newModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageAdapter.this.mModelClass);
            int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);
            mModels.remove(index);
            mKeys.remove(index);
            if (previousChildName == null) {
                mModels.add(0, newModel);
                mKeys.add(0, key);
            } else {
                int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
                int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
                if (nextIndex == mModels.size()) {
                    mModels.add(newModel);
                    mKeys.add(key);
                } else {
                    mModels.add(nextIndex, newModel);
                    mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("FirebaseListAdapter", "Listen was cancelled, no more updates will occur");
        }

    });
}

public void cleanup() {
    // We're being destroyed, let go of our mListener and forget about all of the mModels
    mRef.removeEventListener(mListener);
    mModels.clear();
    mKeys.clear();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mModels.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mModels.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(mLayout, viewGroup, false);
        message_row = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);
    }

    T model = mModels.get(i);
    Message m = (Message) model;
    Log.i("status", m.getStatus());
    if (m.getStatus().equals("sent")){
       message_row.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
       message_row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_bubble_received);
    }
    else {
        message_row.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            message_row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_bubble_sent);
   }
    // Call out to subclass to marshall this model into the provided view
    populateView(view, model);
    return view;
}

protected abstract void populateView(View v, T model);
}
```

I noticed that the getView() is called more times than the count in the list (eg : if I have 2 messages getview() is called 4 to 5 times).
With the current code chat bubbles are always to the left irrespective of the chat status.

[image: on device]

**Firebase Data**

[image]

Comment: A picture of the screen with a description would help us to know where to look in your code, rather than guessing. Also getView() might be called many more times than the count of the list incase something has to be looked up or refreshed. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use two layouts - for your bubbles and your opponent. Use them in `getView()` method of your adapter. For `list_item_message_own.xml` use right allignment and for `list_item_message_opponent.xml` use left allignment, it depends on message status.

```
@Override
public View getView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    MessageCache messageCache = ChatManager.getMessageCacheFromCursor(cursor);
    boolean ownMessage = isOwnMessage(messageCache.getSenderId());

    if (messageCache.getMessagesNotificationType() == null) {

        if (ownMessage) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_own, null, true);
        } else {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_opponent, null, true);
        }

        viewHolder.timeAttachMessageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_attach_message_textview);
        viewHolder.verticalProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vertical_progressbar));
        viewHolder.centeredProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.centered_progressbar);
    } else {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_notification_message, null, true);

        viewHolder.messageTextView = (EmojiTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_textview);
        viewHolder.timeTextMessageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(
                R.id.time_text_message_textview);
    }

    view.setTag(viewHolder);

    return view;
}
```